# Bash/Linux Sort by 3rd column using custom field seperator

Tags: linux, sorting

I can't seem to sort the following data as I would like;

```
find output/ -type f -name *.raw | sort 
output/rtp.0.0.raw
output/rtp.0.10.raw
output/rtp.0.11.raw
output/rtp.0.12.raw
output/rtp.0.13.raw
output/rtp.0.14.raw
output/rtp.0.15.raw
output/rtp.0.16.raw
output/rtp.0.17.raw
output/rtp.0.18.raw
output/rtp.0.19.raw
output/rtp.0.1.raw
output/rtp.0.20.raw
output/rtp.0.2.raw
output/rtp.0.3.raw
output/rtp.0.4.raw
output/rtp.0.5.raw
output/rtp.0.6.raw
output/rtp.0.7.raw
output/rtp.0.8.raw
output/rtp.0.9.raw
```

In the above example I haven't passed any arguments to the `sort` command. No matter what options I used I can't get closer to my desired results. I would like the following output;

```
find output/ -type f -name *.raw | sort 
output/rtp.0.0.raw
output/rtp.0.1.raw
output/rtp.0.2.raw
output/rtp.0.3.raw
output/rtp.0.4.raw
output/rtp.0.5.raw
output/rtp.0.6.raw
output/rtp.0.7.raw
output/rtp.0.8.raw
output/rtp.0.9.raw
output/rtp.0.10.raw
output/rtp.0.11.raw
output/rtp.0.12.raw
output/rtp.0.13.raw
output/rtp.0.14.raw
output/rtp.0.15.raw
output/rtp.0.16.raw
output/rtp.0.17.raw
output/rtp.0.18.raw
output/rtp.0.19.raw
output/rtp.0.20.raw
```

I have tried with `-t .` option to set a field separator to the full stop. Also I have experimented with the `-k` option to specify the field, and `-g`, `-h`, `-n`, but none of the options are helping. I can't see anything else in the man pages that would do as I require, unless I haven't understood the man pages correctly and overlooked my answer.

Can I produce the results I require with `sort`, and if so, how?

Additionally, it's vary rare but sometimes the 2nd column which shows as '0' all the way down may increment. Can that be factored into the sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This makes it:

```
$ sort -t'.' -n -k3 a
output/rtp.0.0.raw
output/rtp.0.1.raw
output/rtp.0.2.raw
output/rtp.0.3.raw
output/rtp.0.4.raw
output/rtp.0.5.raw
output/rtp.0.6.raw
output/rtp.0.7.raw
output/rtp.0.8.raw
output/rtp.0.9.raw
output/rtp.0.10.raw
output/rtp.0.11.raw
output/rtp.0.12.raw
output/rtp.0.13.raw
output/rtp.0.14.raw
output/rtp.0.15.raw
output/rtp.0.16.raw
output/rtp.0.17.raw
output/rtp.0.18.raw
output/rtp.0.19.raw
output/rtp.0.20.raw
```

As you see we need different options:

- `-t'.'` to set the dot `.` as the field separator.
- `-n` to make it numeric sort.
- `-k3` to check the 3rd column.

#### Update

This also makes it:

```
$ sort -t'.' -V -k2 a
output/rtp.0.0.raw
output/rtp.0.1.raw
output/rtp.0.2.raw
output/rtp.0.3.raw
output/rtp.0.4.raw
output/rtp.0.5.raw
output/rtp.0.6.raw
output/rtp.0.7.raw
output/rtp.0.8.raw
output/rtp.0.9.raw
output/rtp.0.10.raw
output/rtp.0.11.raw
output/rtp.0.12.raw
output/rtp.0.13.raw
output/rtp.0.14.raw
output/rtp.0.15.raw
output/rtp.0.16.raw
output/rtp.0.17.raw
output/rtp.0.18.raw
output/rtp.0.19.raw
output/rtp.0.20.raw
```

As you see we need different options:

- `-t'.'` to set the dot `.` as the field separator.
- `-V` to make it sort based on version.
- `-k2` to check the 2nd column.

Comment: It is better to use `sort -V` in this situation as this takes into account the first set of 0s that (as per the question) are sometimes incremented, too.

Comment: Thanks to you both. So I wasn't too far off in my tests I just didn't understand enough to use the correct combination of options. Also I completely overlooked -V so again, thanks.

Comment: Good one, @Phylogenesis, I didn't know the `-V` option for version. Hence, I change my answer to `sort -t'.' -V -k2 file` (col 2 instead of 3, also).

Comment: @fedorqui - In fact, you only need the `-V` option to sort correctly in this instance as it takes into account the dots.

Answer (score 4):

Fedorqui's solution is good (+1), but not all versions of `sort` support `-V`.  For those versions that do not, you need to do a little more work than fedorqui's original solution.  This should suffice:

```
sort -t. -k2,2 -k3,3 -n
```

You get a slightly different sort (eg, '05' sorts before '1' instead of after) if you use:

```
sort -t. -k2g
```

(Note that `-g` is also non-standard, and not available in all versions of `sort`).

Comment: Good one. In fact my first version was like it but today I updated it with Phylogenesis suggestion in comment. I just updated again to show two possibilities. +1 for your answer, neat and clear

Answer (score 1):

```
sort -t'.' -n -k3
```

to sort the 3th column from smallest to biggest

And if you want to sort from biggest to smallest, 
you can use '-r' option :

```
sort -t'.' -n -r -k3
```