# Sort filenames without leading zeros

Tags: bash, sorting

i would like to sort stereo imagefiles with the following pattern

```
img_i_j.ppm,
```

where i is the image counter and j is the id of the camera [0,1].
Currently, if i sort them using

```
ls -1 *.ppm | sort -n
```

the result looks like that:

```
img_0_0.ppm
img_0_1.ppm
img_10_0.ppm
img_10_1.ppm
img_1_0.ppm  
img_11_0.ppm                        
img_11_1.ppm                        
img_1_1.ppm  
img_12_0.ppm
```

But i need to have this output:

```
img_0_0.ppm
img_0_1.ppm
img_1_0.ppm
img_1_1.ppm
img_2_0.ppm  
img_2_1.ppm
...                        
img_10_0.ppm                        
img_10_1.ppm  
...
```

Is this achievable without adapting the filename?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As seen on the comments, use

```
sort -V
```

I initially posted it as a comment because this parameter is not always in the `sort` binary, so you have to use `sort -k -n ...` (for example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929242/1983854)).

Comment: doesn't work on osx: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394536/how-to-simulate-sort-v-on-mac-osx

Comment: @JeffCharter yep, `-V` is just for certain `sort`. That's why I linked a `sort -k -n ...` approach.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` (now?) has the `-v` option, which does what you want. From `man ls`:

```
-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

This is simpler than piping to `sort`, and follows advice [not to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) [parse](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) `ls`.

If you actually intend to parse the output, I imagine that you can mess with `LC_COLLATE` in bash. Alternatively, in zsh, you can just use the glob `*(n)` instead.