# How to simulate "sort -V" on macOS

Tags: macos, git, bash, sorting, gnu

I have written a bash script that I need to work identically on linux and macOS that relies on the `sort` command. I am piping the output of `git tag -l` to `sort`, to get a list of all the version tags in the correct semantic order. GNU offers `-V` which makes this automagic but macOS does not support this argument, so I need to figure out how to accomplish this sort order without it.

```
6.3.1.1
6.3.1.10
6.3.1.11
6.3.1.2
6.3.1.3
...
```

needs to be sorted as

```
6.3.1.1
6.3.1.2
6.3.1.3
...
6.3.1.10
6.3.1.11
```

Comment: Install GNU sort via homebrew `brew install coreutils`. `brew info coreutils` for more information.

Comment: Not sure when it was added, but at least as of Mojave (macOS 10.14), `sort` _does_ support `-V`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use additional features of `git tag` to get a list of tags matching a pattern and sorted properly for version tag ordering (typically no leading zeros):

```
$ git tag --sort v:refname
v0.0.0
v0.0.1
v0.0.2
v0.0.3
v0.0.4
v0.0.5
v0.0.6
v0.0.7
v0.0.8
v0.0.9
v0.0.10
v0.0.11
v0.0.12
```

From [`$ man git-tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

```
   --sort=<type>
       Sort in a specific order. Supported type is "refname
       (lexicographic order), "version:refname" or "v:refname" 
       (tag names are treated as versions). Prepend "-" to reverse 
       sort order. When this option is not given, the sort order
       defaults to the value configured for the tag.sort variable
       if it exists, or lexicographic order otherwise. See 
       git config(1).
```

Comment: This is a superior answer because it is platform-independent and does not require the use of sort at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can download coreUtils from http://rudix.org/packages/index.html

It contains `gnusort` with support `sort -V` sintax

Answer (score 4):

`brew install coreutils`

If corutils are installed you should have gsort on your Mac

`gsort --version`

Comment: if you are "missing" functionality from mac cli, coreutils is a must

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/\b\([0-9]\)\b/0\1/g' versions.txt  | sort | sed 's/\b0\([0-9]\)/\1/g'
```

To explain why this works, consider the first `sed` command by itself.  With your input as versions.txt, the first `sed` command adds a leading zero onto single-digit version numbers, producing:

```
06.03.01.01
06.03.01.02
06.03.01.03
06.03.01.10
06.03.01.11
```

The above can be sorted normally.  After that, it is a matter of removing the added characters.  In the full command, the last `sed` command removes the leading zeros to produce the final output:

```
6.3.1.1
6.3.1.2
6.3.1.3
6.3.1.10
6.3.1.11
```

The works as long as version numbers are 99 or less.  If you have version numbers over 99 but less than 1000, the command gets only slightly more complicated:

```
sed 's/\b\([0-9]\)\b/00\1/g ; s/\b\([0-9][0-9]\)\b/0\1/g' versions.txt  | sort | sed 's/\b0\+\([0-9]\)/\1/g'
```

As I don't have a Mac, the above were tested on Linux.

UPDATE:  In the comments, Jonathan Leffler says that even though word boundary (`\b`) is in Mac regex docs, Mac `sed` doesn't seem to recognize it.  He suggests replacing the first `sed` with:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\./0&/; s/\.\([0-9]\)$/.0\1/; s/\.\([0-9]\)\./.0\1./g; s/\.\([0-9]\)\./.0\1./g'
```

So, the full command might be:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\./0&/; s/\.\([0-9]\)$/.0\1/; s/\.\([0-9]\)\./.0\1./g; s/\.\([0-9]\)\./.0\1./g' versions.txt | sort | sed 's/^0// ; s/\.0/./g'
```

This handles version numbers up to 99.

Comment: Since the code needs to work on Linux as well as on Mac, the test on Linux was valid.  You seem to be using the `\b` (word boundary) option to sed. Unfortunately, although `\b`' is mentioned in `man 7 re_format` on Mac OS X 10.9.1, the `sed` does not seem to recognize it, with or without the `-E` option. 'Tis a nuisance! You'll probably have to use `sed 's/^[0-9]\./0&/; s/\.\([0-9]\)$/.0\1/; s/\.\([0-9]\)\./.0\1./g; s/\.\([0-9]\)\./.0\1./g'` instead. The repeated substitution is necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thanks much! The fourth substitution can be removed, can't it?

Comment: No; unfortunately.  The trouble is that given input 6.3.1.1, the first regex matches `6.`, the second `.1`, the third matches `.3.`, and the `g` can't rematch the second `.`, so without the fourth substitute, you get `06.03.1.01`.

Comment: It doesn't sort according to the SEMVER standard.. I get this order of sorting:

0.0.4
0.0.10-SNAPSHOT
0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
0.0.4-5e2ddb1-SNAPSHOT
0.0.4-SNAPSHOT
0.0.5-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @RoyB I just tried it with those names and the order I get is: 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
0.0.4
0.0.4-5e2ddb1-SNAPSHOT
0.0.4-SNAPSHOT
0.0.5-SNAPSHOT
0.0.10-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 3):

The standard sort that comes installed on OS X can sort by fields using a separator.  So you can sort the version numbers and any suffixes.

This will sort by suffix first and then by the X.Y.Z parts  `sort -s -t- -k 2,2n |  sort -t. -s -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n`, which can also sort the -N-g format version number from the `git describe --tags` command

```
0.11.1
0.11.4
0.11.9-1-ge6b0c59
0.12.0
0.12.1
0.12.2-1-g2d0a334
0.13.0
0.13.0-1-g7711b16
0.13.0-2-g32f91bd
0.13.0-3-g83e21c5
0.14.1-alpha
0.14.1
0.14.2
```

The -3-g83e21c5 above is an example of a suffix that the `git describe --tags` command will automatically append to the latest tag to to signify the number of commits since the tag (3), and the Git SHA hash of the most recent commit (83e21c5)

To reverse the sort into descending order do this: `sort -s -t- -k 2,2nr |  sort -t. -s -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr -k 4,4nr`

Or you can define a shell function around it.

```
   version_sort() {
        # read stdin, sort by version number descending, and write stdout
        # assumes X.Y.Z version numbers

        # this will sort tags like pr-3001, pr-3002 to the END of the list
        # and tags like 2.1.4 BEFORE 2.1.4-gitsha

        sort -s -t- -k 2,2nr |  sort -t. -s -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr -k 4,4nr
    }
```

or write it into a little file named version-sort, and put into some directory on your PATH.   Be sure to `chmod +x` on the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sort -s -t- -k 2,2nr |  sort -t. -s -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr -k 4,4nr
```