# List (ls) filenames with numbers in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, ls

In GNU-Linux, `ls -v` sorts filenames that have numbers in the correct order:

```
file_1.f
file_2.f
file_10.f
file_11.f
file_100.f
```

However, in Mac OS X, `ls -v` does not do the trick:

```
file_1.f
file_10.f
file_100.f
file_11.f
file_2.f
```

I have found [this previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394536/how-to-simulate-sort-v-on-mac-osx) using `sed`, but I'm trying to see if there's a simpler way. The only simple solution I've found, below, only works if the filename starts with a number:

```
file_1.f
file_10.f
file_100.f
file_11.f
file_2.f
1.f
2.f
10.f
11.f
100.f
```

So, as a last resource it would be a matter of removing the prefix ("file_"), e.g. with Automator, and then adding it back in, but this path is probably longer than the `sed` one. It seems surprising that this can't be done in a simpler way. Does anybody know of something more generic and simple? Thanks!

Comment: The `-v` option is non-standard and not portable.  See the linked question for a portable way to sort in that order.